# Difference between prepend_urls and urlpatterns in urls.py

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I have a REST API on Django with TastyPie, which includes on a resource, say `ProductResource`. This resource is accessible via http://my_url/api/product.

I also have a function in my `ProductResource` class called `addNew` which is supposed to handle requests to add new Product. I want to link this method to a url such as http://my_url/api/product/new.

One option is to override `prepend_urls` like this:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/addNew%s$" %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('addNew'), name="product_add_new"),
    ]
```

This works as expected. I assume the other option is to use urls.py, and define the end point there. I have tried to do so, and have added this line to my `urlpatterns`:

```
url(r"^(?P<resource_name>ProductResource)/addNew/$", ProductResource.addNew, name="product_add_new")
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
unbound method addNew() must be called with ProductResource instance as first argument (got WSGIRequest instance instead)
```

Which is understandable. So my question is if it's possible to bind a method inside a resource to a url via `urls.py` instead of `prepend_urls`? if yes, what would be the correct syntax? if no, what is the difference between `prepend_urls` and `urls.py`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't map a method like addNew to a url directly because a callable used in url() must receive as first argument a request. If you really want to map a url to a resource method you could do:

```
def my_view(request):
    resource = MyResource(api_name='myapi')
    resource.addNew(request)
```

And then map this view in url()

```
url(r"^(?P<resource_name>ProductResource)/addNew/$", my_view, name="product_add_new")
```

About `prepend_urls()` what happens is that what you use as a callable in your url() is the return of the `wrap_view()`, not the method itself. And what `wrap_view()` returns is a callable that takes a request as its first argument.

https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L188